# Certain Div's Not Showing Up

Tags: html, css

I have php based blog. It has always worked fine, but I', re-layout the page and certain divs are now not showing up. I can't figure out why? tHis is the mark up. It the div's with the class hr in them.

```
<div class="hr grid_12 clearfix">&nbsp;</div>

        <!-- Caption Line -->
        <h2 class="grid_12 caption clearfix">Kerry's<span> Blog</span><br /> Keeping you up-to-date on our latest news.</h2>

        <div class="hr">&nbsp;</div>

        <!-- Column 1 /Content -->
        <div class="grid_8">

            <!-- Blog Post -->
            <cms:pages masterpage='blog.php' 
            start_on=k_archive_date
            stop_before=k_next_archive_date
            paginate='1' limit='3' >
            <div class="post">
            <!-- Post Title -->
                <h3 class="title"><a href="<cms:show k_page_link />"><cms:show k_page_title /></a></h3>
                <!-- Post Data -->
                <cms:if k_page_foldertitle >
                    <cms:set my_category=k_page_foldertitle />
                    <cms:else />
                    <cms:set my_category='Updates' />
              </cms:if >
                <p class="sub"><a href="#"><cms:show my_category /></a> &bull; <cms:date k_page_date format='jS M, y'/> &bull; <a href="#"><cms:show k_comments_count /></a></p>
                <div class="hr dotted clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
                <!-- Post Image -->
                <cms:if blog_image >
                <img class="thumb img_left" alt="" src="<cms:show blog_image />" /></cms:if>
                <!-- Post Video -->
                <cms:if video ><cms:show video /></cms:if>
                <!-- Post Content -->
                <cms:excerptHTML count='75' ignore='img'><cms:show blog_content /></cms:excerptHTML>
                <!-- Read More Button -->
                <p class="clearfix"><a href="<cms:show k_page_link />" class="button right"> Read More...</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="hr clearfix">&nbsp;</div>


            <cms:if k_paginated_bottom >
            <!-- Blog Navigation -->
            <p class="clearfix">
                <a href="<cms:show k_paginate_link_next />" class="button float">&lt;&lt; Previous Posts</a>
                <a href="<cms:show k_paginate_link_prev />" class="button float right">Newer Posts >></a>
            </p>
            </cms:if>
            </cms:pages >
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.hr {
border:none; 
border-bottom:1px solid #f0f0f0; 
border-top:1px solid #d6d6d6; 
clear:both; height:0; 
line-height:0; 
width:100%; 
font-size:0; 
padding:0 ;margin-bottom :20px;
}
.grid_12 {
display:inline; 
float:left; 
position:relative; 
margin-left:10px; 
margin-right:10px;
}
```

Am I missing something? I'm not too php savy

Comment: please post your actual generated HTML markup and not the template

Comment: height:0; // why 0 high?

Comment: Alternatively if they are simply not in the HTML, it's probably the `<cms:if>` expressions not evaluating to what you think it should.

Comment: First of all, there's not a single line of PHP in this question, your query is on HTML and CSS, and CouchCMS - that being said, why aren't you using the `<hr>` tag? You can style it and everything.  If you want a horizontal rule, put a horizontal rule in the html.  Styling tips: http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a link to the site?

And are you able to find the missing div's in the source code? If you are, then it can be a CSS problem. If you can't find it in the source code, then it's possibly a PHP problem.

What CMS-system/bloggin-system are you using?